# Question over proof that a nontrivial vector space $V$ over an infinite field $F$ is not the union of a finite number of proper subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently looking at the following proof in my textbook:

A nontrivial vector space $V$ over an infinite field $F$ is not the union of a finite number of proper subspaces.

Suppose that $V = S_{1} \cup \cdots \cup S_{n}$, where we may assume that

$$S_{1} \nsubseteq S_{2} \cup \cdots \cup S_{n}$$

Let $w \in S_{1} \backslash (S_{2} \cup \cdots \cup S_{n})$ and let $v \notin S_{1}$. Consider the infinite set

$$ A = \{rw + v \vert r \in F \} $$

which is the "line" through $v$, parallel to $w$. We want to show that each $S_{i}$ contains at most one vector from the infinite set $A$, which is contrary to the fact that $V = S_{1} \cup \cdots \cup S_{n}$. This will prove the theorem.

If $rw + v \in S_{1}$ for $r \neq 0$, then $w \in S_{1}$ implies $v \in S_{1}$, contrary to assumption. Next, suppose the $r_{1}w + v \in S_{i}$ and $r_{2}w + v \in S_{i}$, for $i \geq 2$, where $r_{1} \neq r_{2}$. Then

$$ S_{1} \ni (r_{1}w + v) - (r_{2}w + v) = (r_{1} - r_{2})w$$

and so $w \in S_{i}$, which is also contrary to assumption. QED

Why is showing that each $S_{i}$ contains at most one vector from the infinite set $A$ contrary to the fact that $V = S_{1} \cup \cdots \cup S_{n}$?

Comment: Because there are infinitely many vectors in the set, but only finitely many that are in the union. Where are the rest of the vectors?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: How do we know that any given $S_{i}$ is not infinite?

Comment: We know that there are only finitely many vectors **from $A$** is each $S_i$. Only finitely many vectors from $A$ can lie in the union. But **all** infinitely many vectors from $A$ are in $V$. It's not about whether the $S_i$ are finite or infinite, it's about $A\cap S_i$ being finite. $A\cap V=A$ is infinite, but $A\cap (S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n) = (A\cap S_1)\cup\cdots\cup(A\cap S_n)$ is a finite union of finite sets, so it is finite.

Comment: If $A\cap V$ is infinite, and $A\cap(S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n)$ is finite, then $V\neq S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thank you for your clear response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $A$ is infinite and contained in $V$, so $A\cap V=A$ is an infinite set.

On the other hand, you showed that for each $i$, $A\cap S_i$ is finite (in fact, has at most one element).

So $A\cap(S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n)=(A\cap S_1)\cup\cdots\cup (A\cap S_n)$ is a finite union of finite sets, and therefore is finite.

So we have concluded that $A\cap V$ is infinite, while $A\cap (S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n)$ is finite. That means that $V\neq S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n$.

Note that this need not be cast as a proof by contradiction. It's a proof by contrapositive: id $S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n$ is a finite union of proper subspaces of $V$, then $V\neq S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n$.